# Habitat Gulpfile.js error in Visual Studio but OK on Cmd Line

Tags: habitat, gulp

In the Task Runner Explorer, gulpfile.js is failing to load, and in the output window I'm seeing

```
gulp.task('CI-html', () => {
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

If I comment out CI-html, Im getting another error on a let statement.

But when I run gulp from the command line in my project directory, it is not producing any errors.

Any ideas what could be the difference? Both are run with administration privilidges ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically a Node version issue.  Assuming that you've downloaded the latest NodeJS and installed it (which means its location should be one of your system's  environment variable PATH), just move up the $(PATH) location above the `(DevEnvDir)|Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External`

For VS2015:

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions >  External Web Tools

For VS2017:

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools

If it's not, you could either add the NodeJS location in the PATH environment variable or you can just directly add it on your Visual Studio [shown on Shriroop's blog post](https://exploringsitecore.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-gulp-tasks-not-working-for-sitecore-habitat/).

Comment: My bad...updated it with more info and direct answers.

Comment: Perfect - worked for me :)

Comment: Essentially () => is the "fat" arrow which is part of the EcmaScript 6 syntax.  That's why you need a newer version of NodeJS to run this code.  Same is the case with `let`. This is also part of EcmaScript 6.